# (Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64bits) App crash with dump on "open" or "save as" actions

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-8.1

I'm totally new to QGIS, i've got a user who asked me to install it on his notebook (Lenovo S1 Yoga).

I've tried 2.8 to 2.12 versions without success, everytime we use "open" or "save as" actions (but not limited to these actions i think) the app crash with dump.

I've also tried :

- Run under an local admin session (users have limited privileges) : Crash
- Install on a desktop PC (same OS and barely same configuration) : OK
- Install on a Surface Pro 3 (same OS / same configuration) : Crash
- Disable all default plugins : Crash

It's seems to be Windows Explorer related, but i can't find why.
I've turned Windows Firewall off, but same issue, i might try on a direct Internet connection (we've got a proxy on our main network).

How analyse the dump files ? Any others ideas?